# How to detect audio/video content on website

Tags: c++, google-chrome, audio, video, youtube

I would like to develop browser extension-like addon for detecting audio/video content on page (from youtube, tedtalks, ...). Could someone push me in right way to find more information, or what to look for ? 
Thanks in advance
EDIT: Is there some basic way to approach this content on every site?

Comment: You can search for media like content in the page (either by their extension or content-type header).
Notice that there already is a ton of extension that do thing like that, and that most content providers "hides" their content with tokens and obfuscations. Making it pretty difficult to find a generic appoach.

Comment: Your question is _way_ too broad for Stack Overflow. Right now it's the size of a large boulder, you need to shrink it down to a tiny pebble.